# How do I use Twilio to receive text messages from users and reply to that text with a message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

1.) User sends a text message to a designated Twilio phone number
2.) Application receives this message and parses it for actionable data 
3.) Application replies to sender with a text message delivering the requested information

How the heck do I do this with rails?!

Comment: See http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms and http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your business logic doesn't take that long to execute, it's pretty simple to process a text and send a response. Here are the core steps:

1. Grab the [twilio-ruby](https://www.twilio.com/docs/ruby/install/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=stackdocsupdate) helper library.
2. Point your SMS Url to the Rails controller/action you'd like to invoke
3. Process the [incoming request](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#synchronous) & execute your business logic
4. Instead of returning HTML, return [TwiML](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms)

Here's a link to a simple app that does just this:

https://github.com/crabasa/twilio-rails-demo

Update: I've written two detailed blog posts on integration Twilio into a Rails 4.x app: [Part 1](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html) and [Part 2](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/10/twilio-on-rails-part-2-rails-4-app-sending-sms-mms.html).

Comment: Thanks Carter! This definitely helped in moving me along.

Comment: Carter, I'm having an issue receiving the texts From and Body attributes and storing it in my database. I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038654/having-trouble-receiving-texts-in-rails-from-twilio-and-storing-it-in-my-databas Any advice? Thanks in advance!