# Having an issue using Twilio to receive texts in Rails. Receiving nil when storing to the database.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, twilio

I have set up the request URL in my Twilio account to have it POST to: myurl.com/receivetext. It appears to be successfully posting because when I check the database using the Heroku console I see the following:

Post id: 5, body: nil, from: nil, created_at: "2012-06-14 17:28:01", updated_at: "2012-06-14 17:28:01"

Why is it receiving nil for the body and from attributes? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong! The created and updated at are storing successfully but the two attributes that I care about continue to be stored as nil.

Here's the Receive Text controller which is receiving the Post request from Twilio:

```
class ReceiveTextController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @post=Post.create!(body: params[:Body], from: params[:From])
  end
end
```

EDIT: When I dump the params I receive the following: 
"{\"controller\"=>\"receive_text\", \"action\"=>\"index\"}"

I attained this by inserting the following into my ReceiveText controller. @params = Post.create!(body: params.inspect, from: "Dumping Params") and then opening up the Heroku console to find the database entry with from = "Dumping Params".

I simulated a Twilio request with a curl with the following command curl -X POST myurl.com/receivetext route -d 'AccountSid=AC123&From=%2B19252411234'

I checked the production database again and noticed that the curl request did work when obtaining the FROM attribute. It stored the following:

params.inspect returned "{\"AccountSid\"=>\"AC123\", \"From\"=>\"+19252411234\", \"co..."

I received a comment stating: "As long as twilio is hitting the same URL with the same method (GET/POST) it should be filling the params array as well" I have no idea how to make this comment actionable. I'm very new to rails.

Here's my database migration (I have both attributes set to string. I have tried setting it to text and that didn't work either) :

```
 class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
    t.string :body
    t.string :from

    t.timestamps
   end
  end
 end
```

Here is my Post model:

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :body, :from
 end
```

Routes (everything appears to be routing just fine) :

```
 MovieApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "receive_text/index"
  get "pages/home"
  get "send_text/send_text_message"

  root to: 'pages#home'

  match '/receivetext', to: 'receive_text#index'
  match '/pages/home', to: 'pages#home'
  match '/sendtext', to: 'send_text#send_text_message'
 end
```

Here's my gemfile (incase it helps)

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
  gem 'badfruit'
  gem 'twilio-ruby'
  gem 'logger'
  gem 'jquery-rails'

 group :production do
  gem 'pg'
 end

 group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
 end

 group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 end
```

Comment: Body and From are uppercase parameters when Twilio sends them - if Rails params are case sensitive, they won't find it

Comment: It's not working. Still receiving nil on both attributes.

Comment: can you dump the params array? what's there?

Comment: "{\"controller\"=>\"receive_text\", \"action\"=>\"index\"}"

Comment: I attained this by inserting the following into my ReceiveText controller. @params = Post.create!(body: params.inspect, from: "Dumping Params") and then opening up the Heroku console to find the database entry with from = "Dumping Params".

Comment: After searching like crazy my hunch tells me that it might have something to do with my routes file? Am I supposed to set the controller/method to match via POST? I tried this but it doesn't work either.

Comment: If Twilio was actually hitting that controller the Params array should have stuff like your AccountSid and the CallSid. params will contain both get and post params, correct?

Comment: Any idea why Twilio isn't hitting the controller?

Comment: No, but you can simulate a Twilio request with a curl - just do `curl -X POST url.com/route -d 'AccountSid=AC123&From=%2B19252411234'` and then test to see where it goes.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MovieApp</title>
  <link href="/assets/application-7270767b2a9e9fff880aa5de378ca791.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/application-4ba035647248ee9014c15ad129064e95.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="7PZ7hdhLF4sh/K4CgdwzgCXbRjPlBwDKpfwZ3A1lnh8=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is the page where we receive texts from Twilio.</h1>


</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to rails. I apologize in advance if I come across as obviously having no clue what I'm doing. I typed in the heroku console the command that you gave me and I received what I posted above ^^^^

Comment: I substituted url.com/route with myherokuappurl.com/receivetext     Am I supposed to substitute the AccountSid and From? Or type it in exactly as you posted?

Comment: I forgot to thank you for taking the time to assist me with this. I can't wait to get past this road block!

Comment: Okay we're making progress. I just checked the production database again and noticed that the curl request did work when obtaining the FROM atribute! <Post id: 1, body: nil, from: "+19252411234", created_at: "2012-06-14 22:32:40", updated_at: "2012-06-14 22:32:40">

Comment: params.inspect returned "{\"AccountSid\"=>\"AC123\", \"From\"=>\"+19252411234\", \"co..."

Comment: As long as twilio is hitting the same URL with the same method (GET/POST) it should be filling the params array as well

Answer (score 1):

Wow! I finally figured out why this wasn't working. It turns out that I created a new "APP" in my Twilio account and was setting the POST destination URL in this additional app that I created. The issue with this turned out to be the fact that I was using a Twilio sandbox trial account and I needed to paste the POST url into that sandbox entry field in the "Test your app" section.