# Does the twilio-ruby gem handle SMS responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, twilio

The only [reference to SMS on the readme file](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) is regarding sending SMS messages.

```
# send an sms
@client.account.sms.messages.create(
  :from => '+14159341234',
  :to => '+16105557069',
  :body => 'Hey there!'
)
```

I'm wondering if the twilio-ruby gem provides visibility to SMS responses? I want to do some keyword response logic like [the example they give here in PHP](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-build-a-sms-keyword-response-application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an SMS on your Twilio number, Twilio will [make an HTTP request](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) to your server. You can respond to the incoming SMS by responding to the request with XML, like this:

```
<Response>
    <Sms>This is my response</Sms>
</Response>
```

You can either generate the XML response yourself, or the helper libraries contain methods that help you return XML to the client. I would suggest taking a look at the [Twilio Ruby SMS quickstart](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/hello-monkey) for a simple example, and then going from there.

Comment: Thanks... but this doesn't answer the question regarding whether there is a method in the gem to handle it. It sounds like I need to read the user's SMS response by parsing the HTTP Post or XML myself to see what was said. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct, you would need to parse the HTTP post yourself. You are the one generating the XML (to tell Twilio what to send in reply).

Answer (score 2):

For others who may have this issue, I found [this example application](https://github.com/crabasa/twilio-rails-demo) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022471/how-do-i-use-twilio-to-receive-text-messages-from-users-and-reply-to-that-text-w) to be very useful. What you need to do is:

1. Setup your Twilio Number SMS URL to Post to a certain controller in your application (e.g., myapp.com/twilio/process-sms)
2. Add a route to match that URL to the correct action in your Twilio controller
3. Write some simple logic like below to process responses/messages to your number according to your custom business logic
4. Respond, if necessary, using a .xml.erb file like the one below

class TwilioController < ApplicationController

```
  def process_sms
    @city = params[:FromCity].capitalize
    @state = params[:FromState]
    @from = params[:From]
    u = User.find_by_phone_number(@from)
    @user = u.name
    b = params[:Body]

if b.downcase.include?("question")
    @type = "Question"
    @question = u.questions.build(:description => b)
    @question.save!
    render 'new_question.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
elsif b.downcase.include?("contact")
    @type = "Contact"
    @contact = u.contacts.build(:name => b)
    @contact.save!
    render 'new_contact.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
else
    @type = "Not sure"
    render 'not_sure.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
end
```

The .build will create the object and the .save will save the object. Then you just return to Twilio the TWIML that you want to respond to the user. such as:

app/views/twilio/new_contact.xml.erb

```
<Response>
  <Sms>We added a new contact for you.</Sms>
</Response>
```

Comment: Also, Take care# params[:From] contains phone number of user with international code attached. like "+1...."